# Adding JavaScript file in Admin Panel

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, hooks, actions

I am learning WordPress plugin development. I am trying to attach a jQuery/JavaScript file in Admin Panel. I am using below code in plugins `index.php` file.

```
function admin_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/myscript.js');
    }

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','admin_script');
```

Is it correct code ? What is `my_custom_script` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is good.

And that `my_custom_script` is a unique identifier for the script you're enqueueing. You can find the default script handlers/identifiers [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) — e.g. `jquery` for the jQuery library that ships with WordPress.

There you can also find more details about the `wp_enqueue_script()` function, e.g. where should you use the function, the parameters, etc.